# Setting custom environment variables in managed apache airflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, mwaa

We are planning to switch from managing airflow ourselves to Managed Apache Airflow services of AWS. Our original dags use some custom environment variables that need to be set in Managed airflow as well. So far I was not able to find a way to set custom environment variables while setting up airflow environment in MWAA. Please let me know if anyone knows how to set them.

Comment: Is https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/configuring-env-variables.html what you need?

Comment: Yes. But here we can only choose from the available configurations. There is a dropdown that shows up listing configuration options. We can configure only those options. But if I want to define a configuration option by myself as we can do in normal airflow configurations, 
Ex. AIRFLOW__CORE__MYCONFIG = 'something'
I am not able to see how we can do that here.
I require this for 2 purposes, one to directly use them in DAGs and the second, I need to set up ENV variables for my non-DAG scripts in plugins.

Answer (score 6):

An approach for setting environment variables is to use [Airflow Variables](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/variables.html).

In MWAA, you can store Airflow Variables in AWS Secrets Manager. This approach is documented in MWAA's official documentation. Note that this approach requires specific configuration for the MWAA environment. Once the MWAA environment is set up and the variables are stored in AWS Secrets Manager, the variables become accessible through the Airflow Variable APIs.

```py
from airflow.models import Variable

# Normal call style
foo = Variable.get("foo")
```

See [Step two: Create the Secrets Manager backend as an Apache Airflow configuration option](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/connections-secrets-manager.html)
See [Step four: Add the variables in Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/connections-secrets-manager.html)

Answer (score 2):

you should be able to set `core.myconfig` env variable. mwaa accepts it even though its not on the list. mwaa will create AIRFLOW__CORE__MYCONFIG env variable.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to avoid doing that as the Environment variables necessarily have AIRFLOW_SECTION__ as a prefix to them if we do that. Our common files already have specific environment variable names without the prefix of AIRFLOW__SECTION__. But it seems like there is no direct way to set them as we like it. So finally we have decided to go ahead with this approach and change our common files.

Comment: perhaps this one is better: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/samples-env-variables.html

Comment: Already tried this. The ENV variables created here work for the dag files but not for non-dag files.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a custom plugin that generates runtime environment variables.

Link Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/samples-env-variables.html

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by setting them in the configuration options as such:

```
  airflow_configuration_options = {
    "var.my_var" = "my_val"
  }
```

then you can get them by:

```py
my_var = Variable.get('MY_VAR')
```